# Ionic 5, 'Device@latest' is not in this registry

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I'm getting any error while building to android
The error is in ionic 5, it happened before remove the cordova update plugin

Error:

```
'Device@latest' is not in this registry
This package name is not valid, because 
1. name can no longer contain capital letters
Note that you can also install from a tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

complete log:

```
>cordova.cmd build android --device
Discovered plugin "Device". Adding it to the project
Command failed with exit code 1: npm view Device --json
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Device - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'Device@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "E404",
    "summary": "Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Device - Not found",
    "detail": "\n 'Device@latest' is not in this registry.\nThis package name is not valid, because \n 1. name can no longer contain capital letters\n\nNote that you can also install from a\ntarball, folder, http url, or git url."
  }
}
```

Can someone halp me please?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by removing a Divice plugin in package.json file
the problem is because the npm doesn't find the plugin and doesn't accept uppercase in plugin names.